# Time Dependent Work Flow for AFTER option

Tags: community, time-dependent-workflow

I created Workflow Rule that contains several Time Trigger.The requirement is after certain days from the date input ,it will send email notification.The email template will be different based on how many days user miss.So the time dependent workflows are listed below:

1. After 30 days from the date input...send email.
2. After 66 days from the date input...send email.
3. After 90 days from date   input...send email.

My question is, once it send email for 30 days condition and after few days when condition 66 days is met, will it still run action for 30 days because based on logic After 66 days condition also can be considered meet the condition After 30 days?Same goes when the time meet After 90 days condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workflow rule is triggered only **once**: upon creating/editing the record. At that time, if the rule evaluates to true, the email actions are scheduled. So 3 emails will be scheduled, independent from each other. The actual sending of the emails (after x days) will not influence each other, as the workflow rule is not triggered again.

Whenever the record gets updated in the future, the system evaluates if the workflow rules are still true for any pending scheduled emails. If it is no longer true, the pending scheduled email is removed. If it is still true, it remains in place (unless the date input changes. In that case all emails are rescheduled).

Comment: How about if the email purpose is to check whether the user do something since the last date?If user do no action (edit)  since last date, example after 30, 66,90 days is this time dependent workflow can be applied?

Comment: Yes. You need to find out some way to tell whether the user did something. If any update to the record is fine, then you can compare the date input with today() and only schedule the mails if they're equal. Once the record gets updated by the user, the workflow runs again and the scheduled mails will be removed (as they rule does no longer match the criteria).

Comment: I also learned whenever I updated the field, the workflow also will updated.